# move config files with fpm

Tags: debian, deb, fpm

I'm using `fpm` to build a .deb package from a Golang program. The program uses a `.ini` file to run, and there's a `.service` file in order to activate the program as a systemd service.
I'm building the package as follows:

```
mkdir -p $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR && cp $BINARY_NAME $BUILD_ARTIFACTS_DIR
if which fpm; then
    fpm --description '${DEB_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION}' -s dir -t deb -n myprogram \
      --config-files myprogram.ini --config-files myprogram.service --version $VERSION_STRING \
      --deb-user root --deb-group root \
      --deb-systemd myprogram.service \
      $BINARY_NAME=/usr/bin/ \
      myprogram.ini=/etc/myprogram/ \
      myprogram.service=/etc/systemd/system/
      -p ${DEB_PACKAGE_NAME}-${VERSION_STRING}.deb \
```

If I run `dpkg -c ./myprogram_1.0-d71d9a0_amd64.deb` I have:

```
drwxrwxr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/bin/
-rwxrwxr-x 0/0        22287262 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/bin/myprogram
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/share/doc/myprogram/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             144 2021-09-13 04:45 ./usr/share/doc/myprogram/changelog.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             137 2021-09-13 04:45 ./myprogram.ini
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./lib/systemd/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./lib/systemd/system/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             252 2021-09-13 04:45 ./lib/systemd/system/myprogram.service
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             252 2021-09-13 04:45 ./myprogram.service
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./etc/systemd/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./etc/systemd/system/
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             252 2021-08-20 04:00 ./etc/systemd/system/myprogram.service
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2021-09-13 04:45 ./etc/myprogram/
-rw-rw-r-- 0/0             137 2021-08-20 03:52 ./etc/myprogram/myprogram.ini`
```

What I want is that during installation with `sudo dpkg -i mypackage.deb` the file `myprogram.ini` goes to `/etc/myprogram/` and `myprogram.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/`. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution but you missed the file names in the end of the path.
You currently have two options:

1. use an input file where you list all your files. In this case, you specify the option `--inputs myfiles.txt`
2. specify the files in the command line (almost) as you have done.

**Option 1:**
the file `myfiles.txt` content looks as follows:

> ./myprogram.ini=/etc/myprogram/myprogram.ini
> ./myprogram.service=/etc/systemd/system/myprogram.service

**Option 2:**
if you don't have too many files, you can append the files to the command line, but it has to be done in the following way:

```
... [stripped code]
$BINARY_NAME=/usr/bin/ \
      ./myprogram.ini=/etc/myprogram/myprogram.ini \
      ./myprogram.service=/etc/systemd/system/myprogram.service
      -p ${DEB_PACKAGE_NAME}-${VERSION_STRING}.deb
```